# The vote-count-separator between up and downvotes when viewing votes is off-center

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When clicking on a question's votes to see the up- and down-vote tally, the `<div class="vote-count-separator"></div>` appears to be off-center:

[image]

This bug appears on questions of all vote amounts: positive, neutral, and negative.

Comment: It's actually because [someone broke the column](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253550/the-question-is-misaligned-too-far-to-the-right). It's not supposed to be that wide.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: It's a damn bug report. -.-

Comment: @JeremyBanks So a bug report should no longer be posted?

Comment: @JeremyBanks Come on now, let's not continue this trail of unconstructive bickering. It's gone on far enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A fix for this is rolling out now.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253555/130213)

Comment: Will [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290405/the-vote-count-separator-is-off-center) be fixed too?