# The vote-count separator is off-center

Tags: bug, design

This question is similar to "[The vote-count-separator between up and downvotes when viewing votes is off-center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290382/the-vote-count-separator-between-up-and-downvotes-when-viewing-votes-is-off-cent)".

The vote count for [contesting candidates](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) is off-center:

> [image: VOTE_SPLIT_FOR_CANDIDATES]

I've added red lines to show the alignment of the separator. This can also be seen for posts on StackOverflow :

> [image: VOTE_SPLIT]

The bar is bit moved to the left.